# How to find the correlation between timeseries data and plot a graph in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pearson-correlation

I have the following data:

```
String  Value   datetime
hello   10  10/3/2017 0:00
hello   45  10/4/2017 0:00
hello   544 10/5/2017 0:00
hello   677 10/6/2017 0:00
hello   899 10/7/2017 0:00
hello   67  10/8/2017 0:00
hello   88  10/9/2017 0:00
hello   77  10/10/2017 0:00
Hi  55  10/3/2017 0:00
Hi  99  10/4/2017 0:00
Hi  33  10/5/2017 0:00
Hi  22  10/6/2017 0:00
Plant   11  10/3/2017 0:00
Plant   44  10/4/2017 0:00
Plant   55  10/5/2017 0:00
Plant   661 10/6/2017 0:00
```

I want to find the correlation between the string values and plot a line graph with these three columns and i am using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel(r'test.xlsx')
df.head()
##to find the correlation between string and the value
s_corr = df.String.str.get_dummies(sep=' ').corrwith(df.Value)
print (s_corr)
#Plot the graph
df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
df.plot()
```

But when i am plotting the graph is plotting with  datetime and Value but i want to plot with the three columns. How to do it?